# Query run in myphpsql page but not in php

Tags: php, mysql

my query successfully runs in myphpadmin page sql but out put not comes out in php page. when i give single condition result comes but for two condition result not show in php page.

```
$query=mysqli_query($con,"select sum(food) as foodsum from export where month='August'and location='india';");
$result=mysqli_fetch_array($query);
$foodsum=$result['foodsum'];
echo $foodsum;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use prepared mysql statements to prevent [mysql injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). But you are looking for the function [mysqli_real_escape_string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

Code example (not tested) based on your code (and I guess that your table name is `export`):

```
// escaping the variables.
$month = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, 'August');
$country = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, 'india');

// Executing query
$query=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT SUM(food) AS foodsum FROM export WHERE month='$month' AND location='$country';");
$result=mysqli_fetch_array($query);
$foodsum=$result['foodsum'];
echo $foodsum;
```

Answer (score 0):

add "`" to the column name and remove the semicolon from query like this:

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, "select sum(`food`) as foodsum from export where `month` = 'August'and `location` = 'india'");
```